# React Redux ->How can I map over my state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

So I am making a to-do list in React in order to learn redux and I've been wondering how can I use something like the map function to map over the state, so that I can show the data stored within in different divs?
here's my initialState:

```
const tasks=
[
    
]
```

And then there's my reducer:

```
    const taskReducer = (state=tasks,action) =>
{
    switch(action.type){
        case 'addTask':
            return[
                ...state, 
               { 
                id: nextToDo+=1,
                text: action.text,
                completed: false
                }
            ]
        default:
            return state;
    }

}
```

What I want to do is something among the lines of:

```
{tasks.map(task=>
<div>
   <h1>{task.text}</h1>
<div>)}
```

But it doesn't really work, what are some ways I can accomplish this?

Comment: Can you be more specific than "it doesn't really work"?  How does it not work?  Are you getting errors?  Can you confirm that you are mapping over a populated array?

Comment: No, the array is simply empty even after the reducer

Comment: Don't use whole state for storing an unnamed array. Create a parameter `tasks` and store the array there using the reducer to update it. Then, install `redux-dev-tools`: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd to see the state. There may not be enough details to answer your question. Usually you can see an error in chrome console or use `redux-dev-tools` to see step by step whats going on. Try adding anything you think relevant to the question also, e.g. code structure, more code, the best would be to create a tiny example in codepen.io, etc.

Comment: I'll have that in mind, thanks

Comment: Reducer can actually work for an array, so you may be perfectly fine here, but `initialState` should be an object and we use various reducers to update its parts, e.g. an array `tasks`. Try looking here: https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/basic-reducer-structure Their state is an object in which they are updating parts using reducers.

Comment: So I should use multiple reducers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution people, here's the deal, I had to use mapStateToProps. I also had to change from functional to class component. So basically I first split my app in seperate files, one for the reducers and one for the store, here are all my files:

App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import tasksApp from './tasksApp';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import store from './store'
function App() {

  return (
    <div>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <tasksApp></tasksApp>

      </Provider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

TasksApp.js:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import {Button} from 'react-bootstrap'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import $ from 'jquery'
import store from './store'
class tasksApp extends Component {
    render(){
    console.log(this.props)
    const {tasks} = this.props
    let nextToDo = 0;
   
    const addTask=()=>
    {
        store.dispatch({
            type: 'addTask',
            text:  $('.form-control').val()
        })

    }


    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Enter Task</h1>
            <input className='form-control' placeholder='Enter task'></input>
            <Button variant='success' onClick={()=>addTask()}>Add Task</Button>
            {tasks.map(task=>
                <div key={task.id}>
                    <h1>{task.text}</h1>
                    <h2>{task.id}</h2>
                    <h3>{task.completed}</h3>
                </div>)}
        </div>
    )
}
}
const mapStateToProps=(state)=>
{
    return{
        tasks: state
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(tasksApp)
```

store.js:

```
import {createStore} from 'redux'
import taskReducer from './reducers'
const store = createStore(taskReducer)

store.subscribe(()=>
        console.log('Your store is now', store.getState())

    )
export default store
```

reducers.js:

```
import store from './store'
import $ from 'jquery'

let nextToDo = 0;
    const tasks=
    [
        {
            id: nextToDo+=1,
            text: 'action.text',
            completed: false
        }
    ]
 
const taskReducer = (state=tasks,action) =>
{
    switch(action.type){
        case 'addTask':
            return[
                ...state,
                {
                    id: nextToDo+=1,
                    text: $('.form-control').val(),
                    completed: false
                }
            ]
            
        
        default:
            return state;
    }

}
export default taskReducer;
```

Answer (score 1):

You also use redux `connect()` method.

You can export default connect(mapStatetoProps)

for moreInfo:https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect